# Probability of correct detection given conditional accuracies

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose $1\%$ of people suffer from a certain disease. The probability that this disease will be detected during a routine check-up is $0.9$, while the probability that a healthy person will be incorrectly diagnosed of suffering from the disease is $0.01\%$. If someone goes for a routine check up, and it is found that he has the disease, what is the probability that the diagnosis was wrong?

Comment: Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8xlOm2wPAA may also help.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Let $P$ be the probability that you are trying to find. Then
$$P=\frac{W}{D}$$
Where $W$ is the probability that the patient was free of the disease but was diagnosed as having it, and $D$ is the probability that the patient is diagnosed as having the disease. This can be expanded further as
$$P=\frac{W}{W+C}$$
Where $C$ is the probability that the patient actually has the disease and is diagnosed as having it.

Comment: The question asks for the probability that the diagnosis was wrong, which also includes the case where the patient is diseased but is told that he or she is healthy.

Comment: @SuzuHirose No, it says "if someone goes in for a routine check up, and **it is found that he has the disease**, what is the probability that the diagnosis was wrong?"

Comment: yes I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

To start you on your way, express what you are given in symbols:

- Let $D$ represent the event for having the disease.
- Let $T$ represent the event for a positive test result.

> Suppose  $1\%$ of people suffer from a certain disease.

$\mathsf P(D)=0.01$

> The probability that this disease will be detected during a routine check-up is $0.9$,

$\mathsf P(T\mid D) = 0.9$

> while the probability that a healthy person will be incorrectly diagnosed of suffering from the disease is $0.01\%$.

$\mathsf P(T\mid D^\complement)=0.0001$

> If someone goes for a routine check up, and it is found that he has the disease, what is the probability that the diagnosis was wrong?

Find $\mathsf P(D^\complement\mid T)$ the conditional probability that they don't have the disease given that the test says they do.